# Lenovo ideapad gaming 3 is my laptop, using a zebronics usb hub zeb100hb. It only delivers power to the devices connected but doesnt recognise inputs

Tags: usb, laptop, usb-hub

I am using my laptop lenovo ideapad gaming 3, while connecting my usb hub, it doesnt work as its supposed to, it only delivers power to devices connected and doesnt take their input such as a mice or a keyboard. I have tried updating the drivers in usb root hub 3 on the device manager, tried disabling the power saving on the device manager root hub, tried adding suspend sleep in the registry but it doesnt seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the hub on another PC? If it doesn't work there, it's broken. Return it. See reviews on Amazon on failure rate...

Comment: Ah you seem to be right, it has a high failure rate, unfortunately i cant return it, thanks for the help!